# inject service that came from an async module

Tags: nestjs

I have a module that import another module. The constructor of my service is not call.

I think I have misconfigure the provider.

a.module.ts

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule, HttpModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ServiceConnector,
      useFactory: async (
        options: ConfigModuleOptions,
        httpService: HttpService,
        currentRequest: Request
      ) => new ServiceConnector(options, httpService, currentRequest),
      inject: [MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN, HttpService, REQUEST],
    },
  ],
  exports: [
    ServiceConnector
  ],
})
export class AModule extends ConfigurableModuleClass {}
```

b.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          identity: configService.get('identity'),
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    })
  ],
  providers: [MyService],
})
export class BModule {}
```

MyService.service.ts

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {
  private _logger = new Logger(MyService.name);

  constructor(
    @Inject(ServiceConnector)
    private readonly connector: ServiceConnector,
  ) {
    console.log(this.connector);
  }
  ...
```

What did I miss? How can I inject a service that is build with registerAsync?

Comment: Are you getting an error? This looks right from what I can tell

Comment: Nothing. Constructor is not call but if I call a method from that service it work but DI are undefined.

Comment: How are you calling a method from that service?

Comment: From a controller. I inject the service in the controller constructor

Comment: Any chance you have this in a repo I can take a look at? The `MyService` should be `REQUEST` scoped, but it all seems to look fine

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, has anyone found a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new with Nest.JS. I didn't fully understand the scopes.

The service I try to inject is a Request scope and MyService wasn't.